# Where does windows 8 store its app(from store) data of "11 days left" or "new update found" ?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

For some reason I have an app that thinks it has new updates, which it does not currently and refuses to do its job. I have to completely uninstall it.
Where does windows 8 use as storage for apps/info of apps ?

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN page at [MSDN/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.aspx) links to "Package" and "PackageVersion". [PackageVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageversion.aspx) seems to be what we want to be looking at, but both pages have the following at the bottom:

```
Requirements
 Metadata       Windows.winmd
```

Googling for Windows.winmd gives me [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Component_Object_Model&oldid=537166943) (oldid'd for futureproofing), which states

```
The API definitions are, however, stored in ".winmd" files, which are encoded in ECMA 335 metadata format
```

How about you try searching for those files? I don't have a Win8 to experiment on right now.